# Spark cluster for java application

Tags: java, big-data, apache-spark

Всем привет

Есть java веб приложение которое принимает большое количество запросов и должно возвращать на страницы пользователей ответы. Пришёл к выводу что нужно использовать кластерную обработку. Взял Spark - быстрая вещь. Но на данный момент возникла проблема с выполнением jar(выполняет запрос к API партнёра - полученные данные десериализуются в модель, удаляются не нужные данные и возвращаются на страницу пользователя) на worker-е. Может ли Spark выполнять из worker-а запросы ?
Если нет то что использовать для организации работы приложения через кластер ?

Или по другому сформулирую вопрос: есть несколько серверов для приложения. Как сделать выполнение запросов к API партнёра в кластере ?

Answer (score 1):

Код выполняется не в Worker'e, а в Executor'e.
В документации [cluster overview](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) описывается, чем является Worker (в нём может быть 1 или несколько Executor'ов, которые уже выполняют разные Tasks).

Чтобы выполнялся ваш код, который использует API других библиотек, добавьте эти jar файлы в  `spark.executor.extraClassPath`,
и пишите код, который будет это делать (в Scala Unit будет сериализован и отправлен на executor, в Java это будет лямбда/анонимный класс/...).

Вот код, где на Executor'ах будет создан обьёкт `HBaseAdmin` (сторонняя библиотека, в этом случае в `spark.executor.extraClassPath` нужно будет добавить библиотеки HBase).

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 100)
rdd.map(i => {
    val hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(rdd.context.hadoopConfiguration) hBaseAdmin 
})
```

А также - [Пример веб приложения с использованием Spark на Java + Spring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OWqAjBBDBA).